# Files.newOutputStream vs FileOutputStream

Tags: java

Originally we had the `FileOutputStream` in Java to create an `OutputStream` that simply pipes the data into a file.

Since Java 7 we can also call `Files.newOutputStream` which creates a Stream for us that behaves exactly the same (except for slight differences in "constructor"-arguments).

At least in the OpenJDK 8 the old `FileOutputStream`'s write method is implemented as a native method, while the OutputStream created by `Files.newOutputStream` creates a `ByteChannel` which is then wrapped by an OutputStream that delegates to the ByteChannel.

The second approach reads quite complicated with all the wrappers a call to write passes through. Some naive performance testing revealed though that the new approach is a tiny bit faster, but this is not very much and hardly worth mentioning. But then maybe I am not picking the best use case.

**What is the reasoning behind the new ByteChannel based implementation in the OpenJDK? Is it speed? Are there cases where this will be actually noticeably faster? Why?**

(I know that this is JRE-dependent and the exact implementation should not be relied on. This is primarily curiosity about the background).

Comment: I think everything lies in the "Some naive performance testing". How did you test it? Could you post your benchmark code?

Comment: Such performance tests are heavily OS dependent; I suspect that the OpenJDK guys _did_ extensive performance testing on as many systems as possible before deciding on this implementation.

Comment: Also, just to clarify: this question has nothing to do with the fact that one wants a `File` and another a `Path`, right?

Comment: @Tunki: Well I just called the `write` method with a single byte a couple thousand times. Anyway: I don't want to trigger a discussion why exactly my implementation suffers from whatever, but get behind the actual reasoning of the implementors.

Comment: See my answer; you may get a more clear picture about what is at stake here. `Path`s can be much more than local files!

Comment: FileInputStream / FileOutputStream Considered Harmful: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/fileinputstream-fileoutputstream-considered-harmful

Answer (score 3):

> while the OutputStream created by Files.newOutputStream creates a ByteChannel which is then wrapped by an OutputStream that delegates to the ByteChannel.

THis is not always true. This depends on the `FileSystem` implementation! Or, more accurately, on the `FileSystemProvider` implementation.

The *default* implementation indeed is this (note: not OpenJDK but Oracle's 8u75, so close enough):

```
public OutputStream newOutputStream(Path path, OpenOption... options)
    throws IOException
{
    int len = options.length;
    Set<OpenOption> opts = new HashSet<OpenOption>(len + 3);
    if (len == 0) {
        opts.add(StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        opts.add(StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    } else {
        for (OpenOption opt: options) {
            if (opt == StandardOpenOption.READ)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("READ not allowed");
            opts.add(opt);
        }
    }
    opts.add(StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
    return Channels.newOutputStream(newByteChannel(path, opts));
}
```

But *it does not have to be this way*.

Another `FileSystemProvider` implementation may very well choose to directly return an `OutputStream` instead and wrap `.newByteChannel()` calls using, for instance, [`Channels.newChannel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel-java.io.OutputStream-).

So, the answer really is: it depends. But the OpenJDK guys are not beginners and if they have made that choice, they had a good reason.

And yes, they certainly did performance testing :p

---

Case in point: I have a JSR 203 implementation over Dropbox (code is quite old though); in this implementation, the `FileSystemProvider` calls [this method](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-dropbox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/fs/dropbox/driver/DropBoxFileSystemDriver.java#L82) for `.newOutputStream()`. And in fact `.newByteChannel()` is not even supported (after talking with the experts at nio-dev, though, it appears that this is a bug; but the documentation doesn't mention that an implementation is required)

Comment: "But the OpenJDK guys are not beginners and if they have made that choice, they had a good reason." --> Yes, I hope so. However the ultimate question is not whether the reason is good or bad, but the question is: What is the reasoning like?

Comment: The reasoning is that when it comes to "low level" I/O methods like any `*Stream`/`*Channel` read/write operations, they all eventually end up with native mappings (FOR DEFAULT FILESYSTEM IMPLEMENTATIONS!). Which means (but please note: that is my guess) that given their experiments, they found that ultimately `*Channel` gave enough of a performance edge that they decided that the default `FileSystem` method implementations had to be written as such. But for a really complete, detailed answer, you probably want to ask that question on OpenJDK's nio-dev list.